# Token in permissions dissapears using documentdb and xamarin forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to send permissions for documentdb for a specific user from my azure server to my client app, which are xamarin forms.

On server side everything looks good and I can see users specific permissions and token.

[image: Server side]

But when permissions are received in the client, the token is stripped away, why? 
I am new with documentdb so hopefully it is just me.

[image: Client side]

I am using an Azure Mobile App service as backend.
My backend controller returns an object holding properties for documentdb database including a list of permissions for the user.

```
    public class DbConfig
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string CollectionId { get; set; }
    public string EndpointUri { get; set; }
    public IList<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

}
```

I create a permission for a user for the entire collection if not already created.

```
        public async Task<Permission> CreatePermissionAsync(string resourceLink, string userLink, PermissionMode mode, string resourcePartitionKey = null)
    {
        try
        {

            Permission permission = new Permission
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                PermissionMode = mode,
                ResourceLink = resourceLink
            };

            if (resourcePartitionKey != null)
            {
                permission.ResourcePartitionKey = new PartitionKey(resourcePartitionKey);
            }

            var result = await client.CreatePermissionAsync(userLink, permission);
            DbConfig.Permissions.Add(result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"##### Exception: {e}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I retrieve permissions for a user with this method.

```
        public List<Permission> GetPermissionsForUserPermissionLink(User user)
    {
        var permFeed = client.CreatePermissionQuery(user.PermissionsLink);
        List<Permission> permList = new List<Permission>();

        foreach (Permission perm in permFeed)
        {
            permList.Add(perm);
            DbConfig.Permissions.Add(perm);
        }

        return permList;
    }
```

On the client side in my Xamarin forms app i use this call to my custom controller in the backend.

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "userid", Settings.AzureUserId } };
dbConfig = await client.InvokeApiAsync<DbConfig>("Settings", HttpMethod.Get, parameters);
```

When i look at the permissionlist in the dbConfig object the token for a permission is null. My thought was that I could instantiate a documentdb client based on the permissionslist but it fails.

```
        public void CreateDocumentDbClient(DbConfig config)
    {
        client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(config.EndPointUri), config.Permissions);
        collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(config.DatabaseName, config.CollectionId);
        IsInitialized = true;
    }
```

**EDITS MADE FROM ANSWER**

Just for finish up upon question.
I created a custom class holding both Permission and Token

```
    public class PermissionCustom
{
    public Permission  Permission { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

This makes it possible to create a documentdb client like this:

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(config.EndPointUri), config.Permissions[0].Token);
```

So far so good :-) but it doesn't makes it easier to secure your database considering users could have many permissions for different resources. Even though it is properly to make it more secure, the token is readonly in the first place.

Comment: Are you mean that you use `CreatePermissionAsync` for generating the permission or retrieve the created permission for a specific user, then send to your mobile client? What is your backend (azure mobile app or web api) ? Could you provide the code for sending permission in your backend and code for receiving response in your mobile app?

Comment: Just updated question with code, thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, I have checked this issue and found I could encounter the same issue. When you invoke `client.InvokeApiAsync<DbConfig>("Settings", HttpMethod.Get, parameters);`, you would send request with the following link:

`https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/settings?userid={Settings.AzureUserId}`

By using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you could find that the token has been sent to your mobile client as follows:

[image]

But when deserialize it to `Permission`, the token has not been initialized correctly. I found that the token property is read only as follows:

[image]

In summary, I recommend that you need to define your custom `Permission` class and refer to the `Permission` class provided by DocumentDB client SDK for defining the properties you need within your custom permission class in your mobile client.